# Simplifying this boolean algebra

Tags: math, boolean-logic, algebra, boolean-algebra

Is it possible to simplify this boolean algebra? I want to remove the redundancy of using twice the X variable, but can't seem to see a way how.

(X AND Y) OR NOT(X AND Z)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean logic / [math.se] instead of directly about programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's equivalent to

```
(X AND Y) OR (NOT X OR NOT Z)
```

which is equivalent to

```
(X AND Y) OR NOT X OR NOT Z
```

which is equivalent to

```
(X OR NOT X OR NOT Z) AND (Y OR NOT X OR NOT Z)
```

which is equivalent to

```
(TRUE) AND (Y OR NOT X OR NOT Z)
```

(since `X or NOT x == true` and `TRUE OR Z == true`)

which is equivalent to

```
Y OR NOT X OR NOT Z
```

You can also use a [K-map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) to find an equivalent logical expression, but those are harder to type :)

Answer (score 1):

This is equal to !(X and !Y and Z).

You could also have the formula
(!X or Y or !Z)

You could confirm the answers in http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28X+AND+Y%29+OR+NOT%28X+AND+Z%29

Answer (score 1):

In the Karnaugh map, you can see that your expression is indeed equivalent to a sum of three single-literal terms:

```
not x or y or not z    

             yz
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   0  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
x     +---+---+---+---+
   1  | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

As pointed out by Elye, the single 0 can be expressed as an inverted term with three inputs:

```
not (x and not y and z)
```